# Meaure Zero of the XY Plane

Tags: measure-theory

> Prove that the $XY$-plane has measure zero in $\mathbb R^3$.

I am learning about measure zero in Analysis and I understand that it would have measure zero if it can be broken down into a covering of rectangles.

I also read that all the subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ whose dimension is smaller than $n$ have null Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb R^n$. For instance straight lines or circles are null sets in $\mathbb R^2$.

I am wondering if someone can tell me how they came to that result.

Answer (score 2):

$
\Bbb R^2\times \{0\}
 = \bigcup [-n,n]\times [-n,n]\times \{0\}$ is a denombrable union of subsets.
Now just use the union bound.